# C# Dynamic ListView with CheckBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I've 3 different `DATA` will load dynamic to `_ListView`.
With `DATA1` I need to add more column for showing checkbox control in every row.

I can't get it work, output shows CheckBox as String like below

[image: screenshot]

detail of CS file:

```
public void DataLoad1()
{


            var rowDT = data.GetListData();

            string[] str = new string[rowDT.Columns.Count];

            // loop data
            foreach (DataRow row in rowDT.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= rowDT.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    str[i] = row[i].ToString();
                }


                // create checkbox
                CheckBox chk = new CheckBox
                {
                    // checkbox properties
                    Content = str[0],
                    IsChecked = false,
                    IsEnabled = true
                };

                _listView.Items.Add(
                    new
                    {
                        chkBox  = chk,
                        DocNo   = str[0],
                        QtyReq  = str[1],
                        Price   = help.ThousandSeparator(str[2]),
                        Date    = help.ConvertDate(str[3]),
                        Status  = help.ConvertStatus(str[4]),
                        Confirm = help.ConvertConfirmed(str[5])
                    }
               );

            }
        }
```

here is detail of XAML file :

```
<ListView x:Name="_listView" Height="365" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1" />
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ListView>
```

is it possible i can achieve this without editing XAML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add checkbox in template

```
var gridView = new GridView();

        FrameworkElementFactory FEF = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        FEF.AddHandler(CheckBox.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(CheckBox_CheckChanged), true);
        Binding CBG = new Binding("DocNo");
        FEF.SetBinding(CheckBox.ContentProperty, CBG);

        Binding SBG = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("chkBox"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
        };
        FEF.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, SBG);

        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn()
        {
            Header = "CheckBox",
            CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = FEF }
        });

        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "DocNo", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("DocNo") });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "QtyReq", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("QtyReq") });
        gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn() { Header = "price", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Price") });

        _listView.View = gridView;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            _listView.Items.Add(
                new
                {
                    chkBox = true,
                    DocNo = i + "test",
                    QtyReq = i + "test",
                    Price = i + "test"
                }
           );
        }
```

[creating-wpf-check-list-box-using-c-sharp-code-behind](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-wpf-check-list-box-using-c-sharp-code-behind1)

in above sample using test data , replace with original data

Answer (score 0):

That should probably help you achieve what you need, although the logic here is not very efficient.

```
<ListView x:Name="_listView" 
    Height="365" 
    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,1" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                           <CheckBox Content="{Binding DocNo}" IsChecked="{Binding Checked, Mode=OneWay}"/>  
                       </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DocNo}" Header="Request Number" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding QtyReq}" Header="Requested to UL" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" Header="Date" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Confirm}" Header="Received" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and cs

```
public void DataLoad1()
{
    var rowDT = data.GetListData();

    // loop data
    foreach (DataRow row in rowDT.Rows)
    {
        var str = row.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToList();

        _listView.Items.Add(new {
            Checked = false,
            DocNo   = str[0],
            QtyReq  = str[1],
            Price   = help.ThousandSeparator(str[2]),
            Date    = help.ConvertDate(str[3]),
            Status  = help.ConvertStatus(str[4]),
            Confirm = help.ConvertConfirmed(str[5])
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can we do this without editing XAML? because other DATA2, DATA3 is different size column?